# ViewController Undo Segue in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbar, segue

In iOS 7 when I tap the tab-bar it "undo's" my push segue... For example if I push segue to another view controller and the tap the Tab-Bar it goes back to the old view controller. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard operation of a `UITabBarController`, and has been since iOS 2, as far as I'm aware.

You can prevent this happening by setting a `delegate` of the `UITabBarController` and handling like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
    return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController;
}
```

Comment: Really? I never noticed till now.